# 32-bit Flash player in 64-bit Safari: how?

Tags: macos, safari, 64-bit, webkit, flash

Yes, I know, WebKit uses a separate 32-bit process to play Flash and communicate with it.

But how does Flash draw in a browser? In Mac OS X you cannot draw on a foreign window or reparent your one.

So if the Flash player hosts in another process, how can it obtain the browser window's context (CGContextRef) and be drawn in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't seen the source, so I don't know, but I believe that the flash process just draws into a memory buffer (like drawing into an NSImage, etc.) which is transfered to Safari using interprocess communication. It may be fancier than that (with shared memory, etc.), but that's the gist of it.